# Javascript Origins for Embedded Feeds in Mobile Webview

Tags: yammer

I have developed an app which loads a html document from the mobile app storage that contain Yammer Embedded Feed javascript.

Recently, our company's Yammer admin received a message from yammer, telling that all Yammer Embedded Feed javascript will not work unless the domains have been specified in the "Javascript Origins" section.

However, since we are loading the html page directly from mobile, it is just like opening a html page in web browser with "file://" as domain. Can I add "file://" in the "Javascript Origins"? I have tried to "alert" the "window.location" and it returns "about:blank" on the mobile browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question over on the O365 Network, but let me add the answer here too in case someone has a similar question in the future.

The recent push to update your Yammer app's JavaScript Origins (documented/instructions here http://naomimoneypenny.com/2015/02/11/yammer-apps-javascript-origins-update/) affects only those using the JS SDK (specifically https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js).

It does not affect those using the Embed feed (specifically https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js)